# AppleScript-Photoshop: How to select (like lasso tool) using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, photoshop

Is there a way I can programmatically make a selection in a layer using AppleScript in Photoshop? Similar to how you can make a selection using Lasso Tool. Maybe pass in an array of coordinates? I need to fill that selection later on..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record an action inside Photoshop itself - no need to use AppleScript.

Open the Actions palette, click "Create new action", and give the new action a name. It should automatically start recording what you do. Make your selection in the document, and whatever else you need to do, and then click the stop button, to stop recording.

Now you have an action that will always make that same selection.

If you still need AppleScript for other purposes, you can use it to trigger the action inside Photoshop, if you want:

```
 tell app "Adobe Photoshop" to do action "ActionName" from "NameOfActionSet"
```

where "ActionName" is of course the name of the action you recorded, and the "NameOfActionSet" is the name of the set/group/folder the action belongs to in the Actions palette. (you must type the names exactly as the appear in Photoshop)